# How to find buggy code in android studio open source project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using an open source project from the github called as [AndroidScannerDemo](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo) when I use it in my app then randomly in android studio logcat, I read this exception.

```
08-31 01:30:55.366 30019-30191/? D/SDK: [null:-1] - SimpleHttpHelper RESPONSE success:
                                        code=200
                                        result=
                                        url=http://alta.eqmob.com/adserver/v1/sdk/installreport/get?network_type=1&gaid=4ec3d346-6b09-4971-89a8-779be4cd26f8&imei=357080052633162&sdk_version=4.3.0.8.4101.1&aid=b20a709cc5df8c6a&os_version=4.2.2&country=GB&version=1&timestamp=1504125054763&token=5e702e6d-6535-0aa3-fdce-b3745a145ff6&pkg_name=com.somedomain.androidscannerdemo&event=0&language=en&add_time=1504125054763&natural=0
08-31 01:30:55.376 30019-30019/? D/SDK: [null:-1] - -----------上传成功---------http://alta.eqmob.com/adserver/v1/sdk/installreport/get
08-31 01:30:55.416 700-934/? D/MotionRecognitionService: light val = 0
08-31 01:30:55.626 700-934/? D/MotionRecognitionService: light val = 0
08-31 01:30:55.666 30240-30240/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.Process.getStartElapsedRealtime, referenced from method ehj.f
08-31 01:30:55.666 30240-30240/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 4734: Landroid/os/Process;.getStartElapsedRealtime ()J
08-31 01:30:55.666 30240-30240/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0008
08-31 01:30:55.746 30019-30165/? E/SDK: [null:-1] - SimpleHttpHelper RESPONSE failure:
                                        code=500
                                        result=wmnpM4qhcllzDhwbRL+jyQ==
                                        url=http://sdk.eqmob.com/v4/cut_v3.php
08-31 01:30:55.746 30019-30019/? E/SDK: [null:-1] - 自然流量跳转失败:pkg=com.somedomain.androidscannerdemo
```

I want to remove this code, where I can find it? I used the android studio `Find in Path` feature but unable to locate it.

Comment: I don't see any exceptions. What seems to be the problem? What did you try to search?

Comment: I didn't try to search anything. I just testing my app with the above library then I read this code in logcat which looks for me as virus. why the app is sending or communicating to server? I want to remove this code from app.

Comment: Looks to me that you have some other app installed in your phone that reports everything you install to a remote ad server. Find that app and get rid of it.

Comment: How can I find? any suggestion?

Comment: start by uninstalling unused and potentially malicious apps

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if its ShareIt app, which is sending the new install data to their servers in China. Found below link
https://www.androlyzer.com/app/com.lenovo.anyshare.gps/4030818/1bb5f27989a6f8e795a959037cadab1fd8d12ee3

[Update 1]

I can confirm that it is ShareIt. After I uninstalled ShareIt and my app, reinstalled my app from Android Studio, I didn't see any log making HTTP call to "http://sdk.eqmob.com/v4/cut_v3.php", which was coming when ShareIt was installed.

Comment: That's mean shareit should not be used?

Comment: It was sending the app details for every install. Maybe that's the only thing I noticed or was visible during development. There can be numerous other things that it might be doing.